# I can not filter a list in a date range SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, xml, eclipse, sapui5

I have a problem:

```html
<DateRangeSelection delimiter= "-" displayFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" 
      dateValue="{path:'/dateValueDRS1'}" secondDateValue="{path:'/secondDateValueDRS1'}"
      minDate="{path:'/dateMinDRS1'}" maxDate="{path:'/dateMaxDRS1'}" 
      change="handleChange"/>
```

```js
handleChange: function(oEvt) {
    var filters = [];

    var query = oEvt.getParameter("query");

    if (query) {
        var to_dat = new Date(to);
        var to_dt = to_dat.toISOString();
        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CreatedAt", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT, from_dt, to_dt);

        filters.push(oFilter);

        var list = this.getView().byId("list");
        var oBinding = list.bindAggregation("items");
        oBinding.oFilter(filters);
    }
},
```

With SAPUI5, I can not filter a list in a date range.

My list (example of a date on my list: `05/11/2014`)

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Hi Ithri, it's really hard to help when the code in the question looses it's formatting. You can edit your question and convert your code snippets into blocks formatted as code by using the button that looks like "{}" (look in the editor's toolbar). Adding some context like "I have 2 files xxxx.file and yyyy.file, here is the code for each" + any relevant output increases your chances of getting great answers. Simply, make it easy for people to quickly help you :-)

Comment: handleChange :  function(evt){
     var filters = [];       
 var v = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Master--hello_world")
 var from_dt = v.getProperty("dateValue").toISOString();
 var to_dt = v.getProperty("secondDateValue").toISOString();           
 var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CreatedAt",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT,from_dt,to_dt);
 filters.push(oFilter);
 var list = this.getView().byId("list");
            
 var oBinding = list.bindAggregation("items");
     oBinding.oFilter(filters);

  },

Answer (score 0):

If `CreatedAt` is of type edm.datetime commenting this line should do the trick.from date also should be date object.

//var to_dt = to_dat.toISOString();